# Material Design Assets

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design

I've got a question about Material Design assets.

In my work I'm supposed to do visualisation of a simple web app. My core tool is Illustrator and the requirement for this site is to be consistent with Material Design. I've seen only icons available for download directly on material design site. But is there any way to get DEFAULT buttons, checkboxes (vectorized ofc) etc.?

Comment: Maybe try googling... https://materialdesignicons.com/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know but on this website you can fine all about material design, colors
scheme, proportion and all the guidelines to make right material design components.

https://material.io/design/guidelines-overview/#addition